# Change figure name in every loop Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, plot, matlab-figure

I'm a beginner in Matlab but I must use it for my master thesis...

I must change the name of my figure and the name of the file I'll save for every loop I've tried that using the function "eval" as in the figure name is supposed to be written, as "Figure - Date which will change at each loops" but the way I used it is wrong. What could another function do this work? Or how do I have to change the setting of eval?

```
NAME={'Sept-Oct 2015','Nov 2015','Jan-Fe 2016','Fev 2016','Mars-Av 2016','Av-Mai 2016','Juin 2016','Juil 2016','Août 2016','Sept 2016','Oct 2016','Nov 2016','Déc 2016'};

for k=1:13
plot(time,data,'g');
eval(title('Figure -' NAME{1,k},'fontsize';14))
axis tight
eval(saveas(gcf,'Figure -' NAME{1,k},'eps'))
end
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Please include a more detailed problem description than "doesn't work", or your question will likely be closed as off-topic.

Comment: What are the `eval`s doing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fixed version of your code, with minimal change, if  I got your intention correctly.

```
NAME={'Sept-Oct 2015','Nov 2015','Jan-Fe 2016','Fev 2016','Mars-Av 2016','Av-Mai 2016','Juin 2016','Juil 2016','Août 2016','Sept 2016','Oct 2016','Nov 2016','Déc 2016'};

for k = 1:13
    plot(time,data,'g');
    title(['Figure -' NAME{1,k}],'fontsize',14)
    axis tight
    saveas(gcf,['Figure -' NAME{1,k}],'eps')
end
```

However, right now you plot 13 times the same figure (with a different title), so I guess `data` and `time` should be indexed somehow. Also keep in mind that this changes the *title* of the figure (which is printed in it), not it's *name* (which appears at the top of the window/tab).

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, data and time are indexed but my code was something like 300 lines and data and time are also looped variables so I wanted to made it look more simple to aim my real problem